# Angle between two vectors confused

Tags: math, vector

I wonder why angle between two vectors is `alpha` but not `beta` or `2*pi - alpha` as below image:
[Angle between two vectors http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/1936/80732467.png](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/1936/80732467.png)

Why the formular: `cos(phi) = (vector a DOT vector b)/(|vector a| * |vector b|)` always returns cos of alpha (but not `beta` or `2*pi - alpha`?

Comment: This is off-topic, it's not programming related.  Consult an introductory textbook on trigonometry or similar source.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I'm currently doing a light effect in OpenGL but I missed this concept :-(

Comment: Please try to add the image otherwise the question does not make sense

Comment: @izomorphius: I thought I did add an image into my question :-(

Comment: @BìnhNguyên its seems the url is not accessible at least for me. Try downloading the image and uploading it from your computer.

Comment: @izomorphius: I have fixed link, hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a (representative) of a vector is a directed segment and by definition the angle between two vectors is the one formed when going counter-clockwise from the first vector to the second. In your case this angle is `2*pi- alpha`. Actaully `cos(2*pi-alpha) = cos(-alpha) = cos(alpha)` so if you care only about the cosine, whether you go clockwise or counter-clockwise won't matter.

Comment: so, the angle in my image is wrong?

Comment: @BìnhNguyên so it seems. If you compute `angle(a, b)` it should be the complementary of the one you have drawn. Note that `angle(a,b)` and `angle(b,a)` are not the same but are complementary!

Comment: If I want to calculate angle between two vector in 3D like this: http://www.technologyuk.net/mathematics/vectors/images/vectors_0020.gif How can I know what direction is clockwise or counter-clockwise?

Comment: Place the vectors in a single plane to be able to compute an angle between them and then apply same rule :)

Comment: One more question please :D, so, Is the first image in this article: http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/routines/r_dot.htm wrong in determine angle between vector v1 and v2?

Comment: @BìnhNguyên so it seems. However keep in mind th author only talks about dot product and the direction of the angle does not matter for that.